# Speedup HashSet and HashMap performance

Tags: java, integer, hashmap, hashset

In Java, I have:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
callVoidMethod(set);
...
public static void callVoidMethod(Set<Integer> set) {

    Set<Integer> superset = new HashSet<Integer>(set);
    ...
    // I just added this loop to show that I'm adding quite a lot
    // well, it depends on conditions, sometimes I add nothing,
    // but it is unpredictable and do not know if add something
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         ...
         if (conditionSatisfied) superset.add(someValue);
         ...
    }

}
```

The code above is simplified, the idea is to pass the set by reference into a void method and create a full copy of a set such that we will be able to add some new elements to the copy (superset here) and do not touch the set as we need it untouched when we exit the void method.

My code works with lots of data processing and if there is no faster way to make a copy, then I would like to optimize the `HashSet` itself, for instance I do not need `Integer`s as keys, but better primitive `int`s. Would be a good idea to implement an `int[]` array of keys in the `MyHashSet`?

If so is possible, I would be interested in using the same idea for improving this:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Item>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Item>>();
```

**EDIT**: I need only speed-performance-optimization. I do not need beautiful-maintainable code and memory.

Comment: is `conditionSatisfied` generally true or false?

Comment: It is actually in a `for` loop and sometimes it is true, sometimes false.

Comment: how many (super)levels can this sets have?

Comment: So the problem is with making this copy. I tried to avoid it by saving elements in the `ArrayList` and then removing them from the set when I exit the loop. Well, the execution time was the same. My second question is about some sufficient implementation of the `HashSet`, I think by managing `int` keys it will be faster.

Comment: to Boris: just one superset (superlevel) for one set. But I call this method often.

Comment: Can this sets be immutable after the creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you do with these objects later? If you're just doing lookups or something like that, it might be faster to keep them separate and check both, rather than making a full copy. So,

```
public static void callVoidMethod(Set<Integer> set) {

    Set<Integer> superset = new HashSet<Integer>();
    ...
    if (conditionSatisfied) superset.add(someValue);

    ...
    if(set.contains(value) || superset.contains(value))
        doSomething();

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, then I call this method recursively :) And thus I pass too many sets in this method, the idea was then to create an array of elements which are those separate HashSets, so for example: first time I call the method I pass an array with one set, then I create the second superset and add it to the array, then call again the method with two sets now... But I ended with the challenge of creating such an array of HashSets.

Comment: Calling it recursively adds to the complexity for sure. Maybe this won't work for what you're ultimately trying to do, but you could make a defensive copy of the set before calling the method the first time, pass the copy and allow it to add to the set like you want. The original set would be unmodified, and all subsequent operations happen on the first copy?

Comment: I've finally implemented an array of `HashSet`s. So thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

In general, if you're looking for high speed collections that allow for primitives, consider using [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/).  I would say - don't optimize unless you've discovered that this is actually a bottleneck.  You or someone else will need to maintain this code, and reading an optimized version is often harder.

Comment: In this specific case, [`TIntHashSet`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/set/hash/TIntHashSet.html) is probably the appropriate tool for the job.  If you need it to be a `Set<Integer>`, wrap that in a [`TIntSetDecorator`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/decorator/TIntSetDecorator.html).  (But that said, I would under no circumstances whip up my own implementation here.)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried first tweaking the HashSet's initial capacity and load factor?

[HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28int,%20float%29)

Here's a post that might help you.

[HashMap initialization parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434989/hashmap-intialization-parameters-load-initialcapacity)

If you have such a big amount of data to process, it would probably payoff to analyze it's distribution and adjust these settings first.

Having tweaked that, it might give a very slight performance to replace Integers with ints, but it might depend more on JVM implementation specifics and hardware configuration than what this improvement alone would give you.