# How does initial capacity impact the performance of a HashMap

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

The [documentation for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) contains the following statement:

> Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or
>   the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

Could someone please explain it. I don't see any method for changing or affecting the load factor of a HashMap

Comment: In most (99.99...%) cases, that does not matter, and to use the default constructor is just fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115445/what-is-the-optimal-capacity-and-load-factor-for-a-fixed-size-hashmap

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your HashMap as part of the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int,%20float%29) argument, you can provide it with both the initial capacity and the load factor:

```
 HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) 
     Constructs an empty HashMap with the specified initial capacity and load factor.
```

You can also look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434989/827480) for some insight on Load Factors and Initial Capacity.

Comment: I don't see how this answers most of the question.

Comment: @delnan The OP asked how to set or change the loadFactor.  Additionally, the provided SO link also explains the relation between initial capacity, load factor and the need for rehashing.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of it. I consider the relationship to performance another large part of the question. But whatever, apparently I'm alone with that perception, so it may also be false.

Comment: @delnan Agreed.  I was unable to provide a proper comprehensive answer to the performance part.  I've actually been looking through the HashMap implementation code to see exactly where/how the iterator was implemented to see how it skips over empty entries but you provided your response before I did.

Answer (score 2):

Both a too large initial capacity and a too low load factor result in a hash table where most entries are vacant. While this decreases the odds of collisions (and thus improves average lookup performance), iterating over the keys/values/items of the hash table requires skipping over more empty slots.

As others have explained, you can give a load factor and initial capacity when constructing the hash table object.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of theory behind a hash table and what makes a "good" hash table for a given input set prediction, I would start with [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Load_factor) (specifically at the "Load Factor" section that's linked).