# What are the () at the end of a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, but I never understood what the () at the end of a dictionary means!

Let's say I have a class, and I declare a field like this:

```
public Dictionary<InventoryType, Inventory> Inventory { get; private set; }
```

And then, on the constructor, I have:

```
Inventory = new Dictionary<InventoryType, Inventory>(6);
```

What does the 6 at the end means? Thank you!

Comment: That's `capacity` which is used to allocate initial memory for your `Dictionary`, if your `Dictionary` grows larger than that, it will be automatically increased.

Answer (score 4):

That `6` is the initial capacity. It's a soft indication for the collection how big it will be, it's not a limit of any kind.

When you know that a collection will hold a certain number of elements it is slightly more efficient to allocate the space for those elements at once. Otherwise the collection will use an algorithm to grow but that involves copying data.

Most collections start with capcity=4 and when that is filled they grow to 8, then to 16 etc. Each time a new internal array (depends on the actuial collection) is allocated and the existing data has to be copied.

And that means that 6 is rather low, and hardly worthwile.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? That the Inventory field can hold up up to 6 objects of Inventory class?

Comment: @user2714359, that the dictionary reserves memory for 6 entries upfront.

Comment: @CMircea wote up for explaining WHY you would want to use this.

Comment: Just some kind of performance improvement. if you know that you will ahve 6 entries it would be some kind be faster because no redimensions will happen. But even if you tell 6 you can add more elements.

As long as you do not know how many elements will be added you can ignore the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xfhwa508.aspx):

> Dictionary(Int32) Initializes a new instance of the Dictionary class that is empty, has the specified initial capacity, and uses the default equality comparer for the key type.

So it's the initial size of the dictionary.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414109/should-a-net-generic-dictionary-be-initialised-with-a-capacity-equal-to-the-num) for why you would want to set the initial capacity.